# Paying habitation tax in France

Tags: taxes, france

I need to send a cheque for my habitation tax in France. What parts of the pay slip (SEPA?) do I need sign and include? I know that I could pay by other methods instead of sending a cheque.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned here : http://www.impots.gouv.fr/portal/dgi/public/popup;jsessionid=DGELSDHW1OYZVQFIEIQCFFI?typePage=cpr02&espId=1&docOid=documentstandard_613&temNvlPopUp=true

EDITED 2017/08 : the above link is dead. You can have informations here : https://www.impots.gouv.fr/portail/particulier/les-autres-moyens-de-paiement

Notice the maximum amount you can pay by *chèque* is now 2000 €.

> Vous pouvez payer par chèque dans la limite de 2 000 €.
>
> En 2017, les montants supérieurs à 2 000 € doivent obligatoirement
>   être payés par prélèvement mensuel ou à l'échéance ou par paiement
>   direct en ligne sur le site impots.gouv.fr ou par smartphone.
>
> Ce montant sera progressivement abaissé à 1 000 € en 2018 et 300 € en
>   2019.

END OF 2017/08 EDIT

> Le paiement par chèque
>
> Vous pouvez payer par chèque dans la limite de 10 000 €.
>
> Si vous utilisez ce mode de paiement ou si vous souhaitez payer un
>   montant différent de celui indiqué sur votre avis d'impôt :
>
> ```
> libellez votre chèque à l'ordre du Trésor public ;
> joignez le talon de paiement, pour servir de référence à votre paiement sans le signer, ni l'agrafer, ou le coller ;
> envoyez votre chèque accompagné du talon de paiement, sans autre document, en utilisant l'enveloppe retour jointe à votre avis.
> ```
>
> Le paiement par chèque est encaissé dès réception.

Which can be approximately translated to :

- set the *chèque* payable to *Trésor Public* and write the appropriate
  amount
- join the part that you can detach from the letter (it displays
  various references number needed) without signing it
- send your *chèque* and the reference document in the return envelope
  that is included in the *impots* letter without any other documents.